# SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, could not upload results to the web interface

Tags: sonarqube

I am running SonarQube for analyzing my C# project. I am running on the console. Despite the fact it says everything is ok, the results are not shown in the web interface. This is the result from the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild:

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
Default properties file was found at E:\Util\SonarQube\bin\Scanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from E:\Util\SonarQube\bin\Scanner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
17:47:44.377  Creating a summary markdown file...
17:47:44.48  Analysis results: http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/Project
17:47:44.481  Post-processing succeeded.

Anyone with the same problem or with a hint on how to detect what is possibly worng?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the status of the project's background tasks: Project *Administration > Background Tasks*

Comment: I have checked and there is nothing there. Not even an error.

Comment: Do you see the project if you login as admin? Did you check the Execute Analysis rights? Did you install SonarQube on a build agent itself (you are using localhost)? What is the version of SonarQube?

Comment: Yes. I see the project, but the last update was from one month ago. The SonarQube is running on localhost as a windows service. SonarQube is Version 7.0 (build 36138). Do not know where to check the Execute Analysis, but I am doing exactly the same analysis and commands that worked before.

Comment: I think the results are not even being sent to the dashboard. There is no pending tasks and no failing tasks.

Comment: What does it say in the summary markdown file? (in _.sonarqube\out\summary.md_)

Try increasing the verbosity of the logging (add _/d:sonar.verbose=true_ to the _begin_ command line call).

Comment: Analysis succeeded for SonarQube project "", version  [Analysis results](http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/Project)
- Product projects: 42, test projects: 2
- Invalid projects: 0, skipped projects: 0, excluded projects: 0

Comment: when I try to access the link, it says the project key is not found.

Comment: I think it may be an environment variable problem, when I call the sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.3.778.jar from the command line, it works successfully.

Comment: When I run sonnar-scanner.bat from the command line with the parameters, it works. When it is called from SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end, it fails.